# Validation error , OBJECT, using swf/flash

Tags: html, object, flash

I'm not understand why it can't pass the validation(

```
<!-- logo -->
 <div id="tdLogo">
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="548" height="170" ><param name="movie" value="swf/logoFinal.swf" />
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swf/logoFinal.swf" width="548" height="170">
  <!--<![endif]-->
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo said LULWORTH Dorset" />
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object> 
 </div>
```

Line 263, Column 90: Element object is missing one or more of the following attributes: data, type.
…44553540000" width="548" height="170" >

Line 263, Column 90: The classid attribute on the object element is obsolete. Use the data and type attributes to invoke plugins. To set a parameter with the name classid, use the param element.
…44553540000" width="548" height="170" >

Comment: because you're missing a `data` or `type` attribute and you've used a `classid` attribute?

Comment: <div id="tdLogo">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="height: 170px; width: 548px" data="swf/logoFinal.swf" >
<param name="movie" value="swf/logoFinal.swf" >
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" >
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" >
<div>
<img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo said LULWORTH Dorset" title="LULWORTH LOGO">
</div>
</object>
 </div>
-{√.ι.ק.}-

Comment: this what I have post min ago working, so can close the topic

Comment: you should add it as an answer to the question, and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

I am using:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashfile.swf" id="loader" name="loader" style="width:640px;height:480px;vertical-align:middle;">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="movie" value="flashfile.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    
</object>
```

Note: No need to use the `embed` tag anymore.